# Software RAID0+1 using 3 disks

Tags: raid, software-raid, mdadm, raid-10

Is it possible to use mdadm to do RAID0+1 using 3 disks?
My scenario is 1x2TB disk and 2x1TB disks. Not interested in the RAID0 performance boost, just want to combine them so I can mirror them with the 2TB.

Thanks

### EDIT:

I'm thinking this is what I might want to do, if it works:

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda /dev/sdb
mdadm --create /dev/md1 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/md0 /dev/sdc
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You need 4.  (At least, with any setup I've seen.)  However, you could use 4 partitions, instead of 4 drives.  Have one side of the mirror use RAID 0 on two partitions on two 1TB drives.  The other side of the mirror could use RAID 0 on two partitions on one 2TB drive.  Ought to work.

I don't offhand know how much you'll get of the usual speed benefit of using 2 drives like what RAID 0 often brings.  (Actually, I'm rather certain it's implementation-specific.  So it might work pretty well, or not.)  But 1 drive of 2TB is likely to be a bit slower than 2 drives of 1 TB each, because the single 2TB drive may require reading from a different part of the drive, instead of having two drives reading/writing different spots simultaneously (since they are separate drives).

Is this the best way to do it?  Maybe not.  (Maybe Server Fault may be a better site for asking such a speed/performance-related question.)  However, regarding the question of whether such a thing is doable, I would say, certainly.  Just tell the RAID software to work with partitions (rather than drives).